# Getting .argmax() in a list appended to an image collection: Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I have appended a list of elevation data to a filtered image collection in GEE as metadata. I now want to find the position of which elevation (e.g. 25 meters) has the highest pixel count using `.argmax()`. I can do this successfully for a singular image, but struggling to work out how this will work for an image collection as a whole (20 images +).

I can't share the entire script for work reasons. The bit I can show is:

```
var newVariable = MyCollection.map(function(imgcol){
  var histogramValues = ee.Image(imgcol).select('elevation').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.autoHistogram(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 2,
    maxPixels: 1e12,
  })
  return imgcol.set('histogramValues', histogramValues.values().get(0))
})
print('Histogram appended', autoHisto)**
```

This returns an image collection with appended histogram values (amount of pixels at a given elevation). I am now struggling to find out where the highest pixel count is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate that you cannot share your complete script. As a matter of fact, even if you could, including it probably wouldn't be ideal. What would be good if you did in the future, is including a boiled-down script, though still **complete and runnable**, focusing **only** on the specifics of your question.

> I am now struggling to find out where the highest pixel count is.

It is not completely clear what you mean with this. I'm guessing that you want the elevation with the highest pixel count, for each image. If so, something like this should work:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').select(['B1'], ['elevation'])
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01')

function addHistogram(image) {
  var histogram = ee.Image(image).select('elevation').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.autoHistogram(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 100,
    maxPixels: 1e12
  })
  var histogramValues = ee.Array(histogram.values().get(0))
  var maxCountIndex = histogramValues.slice(1, 1, 2).argmax().get(0)
  var elevationWithHighestCount = histogramValues.get([maxCountIndex, 0])
  var highestCount = histogramValues.get([maxCountIndex, 1])
  return image
    .set('histogramValues', histogramValues)
    .set('elevationWithHighestCount', elevationWithHighestCount)
    .set('highestCount', highestCount)
  
}

var collectionWithHistogram = collection.map(addHistogram)
print(collectionWithHistogram)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9aaa2926c45084bb42bff9dfd190a1a2

Comment: This worked like an absolute treat - thank you so much for your help and comments! Have a good one